# How does object scaling through different screens work?

Tags: android, screen

I am new to Android, but I still managed to design an app that runs just fine on my smartphone. I read the tutorial about Android support for different screen sizes and I thought: "Ok, that's great, Android itself will scale the app in order to fit other screen sizes. I just need to have different images for different resolutions so that they will look better."
Well, it seems I didn't understand how it works exactly. By using a Virtual Device within Android SDK, I run my app on a smaller screen size. Unfortunately, there was no automatic "scaling" and half of my app layout is not shown on the screen. An imageButton that on my smartphone was one sixth of the screen, it occupies maybe one third of this new smaller screen.
What did I forget? I read some explanations and other posts but the info I got seemed to indicate an automatic scaling that doesn't happen... Maybe I miss some basic rule?
Thank you

EDIT:
Here below I add a bit of my code as an example. How should I change it in order to make the ImageButtons fill the smartphone screen in the same way, even if the screen sizes change? (if it's possible).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/greenbackground"
 tools:context=".GameFrame" >

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/empty" />

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/empty" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image2"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/empty" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yes, for example you might not be using device-independent units. as people here mostly aren't mind readers please attach sample activity and layout code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `ScollView` in order to display UI elements which aren't visible on the small screens. Keep in mind that a `ScrollView` can only have one child:

```
<ScollView
[...] >

  <MyParentLayout
   [...] >

      <MyUiElements
      [...] >

   </MyParentLayout>

</ScollView>
```

Comment: The scrollview is not what I need, thanks, the full app layout should be displayed on the screen.

I use "dp" units. The imageButton are "wrap_content" and I have different image sizes for hdpi/mdpi/ldpi. I will add some sample code later (I didn't add code at first because I was hoping there was some obvious option I didn't set).

Comment: Android does not scale like that. AFAIK this is the only way do it.

Comment: @andr I added my code in the original post, if you can help. "dp" units are resolution indipendent, but perhaps I would need to have a "size independent" unit measure...